# Modal , div id y Dinamic twain problemas la segunda vez que abre

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Buenas noches espero me de ha explicar y me puedan ayudar.

Estoy trabajando en un sistema que registrara ciertas características de los documentos, pero además se escaneara el documento directamente en el navegador por medio de una aplicación con licencia llamada Dinamic Web Twain , que de momento estoy usando la versión de prueba, ya que la de licencia la comprara la empresa después.

Para lograr el escaneado  lo que hago es abrir un modal en la misma ventana , este modal es dinamico ya que en el tengo un id=global para que cualquier parte del sistema lo pueda llamar y cargar la información que necesite en el , para ello cargo en ese id el archivo que necesito por medio de $ajax().

El problema solo se presenta cuando necesito cargar lo necesario para el escaner, según la documentación de Dinamic Web twain debo poner un div con cierto **id** fijo que ellos proporcionan de este modo el div funge como un contenedor tipo vista previa del documento. Esto sirve perfectamente la primera vez que abro el documento, pero la segunda ya no abre el contenedor.

En consola no me muestra ningún error, al inspeccionar el elemento me deja ver que la primera vez en el **id** fijo añade código necesario para la vista previa, pero en la segunda vez no añade nada.

Ya intente ejecutar al presionar el botón de cerrar el modal el siguiente código

```
   $("#modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
   $(this).find("iframe").html("");
   $(this).find("iframe").attr("src", "");
   $(this).off();
```

también probe con :

```
$("#comodin").data("modal", null);
```

Mi pregunta es ¿Creen que si tenga que ver el "id" y que la primera vez lo reconozca y la segunda no? lo raro es que en las demás funciones del sistema funciona perfectamente puedo abrir n veces el modal con información diferente o la misma.
¿Será alguna restricción de Dinamic Web ? Alguien lo ha usada que me pueda orientar?

[image: Asi se ve la primera vez, con el div para vista previa]

[image: Así se ve e moda la segunda vez]

De antemano gracias

Todo inicia con el index en el hago el llamado de todas mis librerias, y en este mismo hago una segmentación con divs para llamar distintos archivos con ajax de query

index.cfm

> Cita en bloque

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 5.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script src="#vCarpetaJavaScript#/funciones.js"></script> 
    <body>
        <div id=contenedor>
            <div class="row">
                <cfinclude  template="compartido/comodinModal.cfm">
                 <section  id="cambiaSegunAjax"  class="container-fluid" style="height:750px;" >
                        <cfinclude template="marcoInicial.cfm">
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>
    <body>
```

En el div con el ID "cambiaSegunAjax" se van cargando diferentes archivos supongamos que en el cargo uno llamado listadeDocumentos en él tengo un icono que la hacer clic llama a la apertura del modal, de la siguiente manera;

```
<img src="css/escaner.png" width="50px" height="50px"  class="manita" style="display:inline; "
         onclick="AjaxModal('escanear/escaner.cfm?registro=#busca#','','CargaDinamica')"/>
```

La sección de AjaxModal() es una funcion a la que le paso tres parametros uno de ellos es la ruta, el otro el formulario y el ultimo en que parte se ha de cargar el archivo que se manda a llamar.

Desde el index siempre aparece incluido el archivo comodinModal.cfm que contiene el código para la apertura del modal y que al estar fuera del div cambiaSegunAjax no se pierde en las llamadas a los diversos archivos.

Comment: Por favor agregá el código HTML para saber cual es la estructura inicial y el código JS donde llamás a la herramienta de escaneo.

Comment: Listo se añadio parte del código que se emplea espero me puedas ayudar , gracias

Comment: Podrías publicar el código de la función `AjaxModal()`? El problema es que te escanea la primera vez, pero al cerrar el modal y realizar otro escaneo no te aparece la vista previa?

Comment: Listo se añadio el código de la función . Correcto la primera vez me aparece perfectamente el marco del div con id = dwtcontrolContainer se escanea y listo, despues se cierra el modal y al quere escanear otro documento presiono la imagen que llama al modal con la información a cargar y no se ve la vista previa , lo interesante es que si se escanea algo y lo guardo si se almacena , aunque no se tenga la vista previa..Gracias por tu tiempo